# Go: Meaning of the 'fmt' package acronym

Tags: go

What does the "*fmt*" acronym mean in Golang? "*fmt*" is a package that provides I/O functions like `Println` (you can import it with `import "fmt"`).

I suppose that the "*f*" means formatting but can't find a proper answer.

Comment: and it's pronounced "fumpt". Don't let anyone tell you otherwise ;)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`fmt` is short for format.  [From the docs](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)

> Package fmt implements formatted I/O with functions analogous to C's
>   printf and scanf. The format 'verbs' are derived from C's but are
>   simpler.

Comment: Why is it pronounced "fumpt" rather than "format" then?

Comment: @KaMok it's pronounced that way because that's how someone might pronounce "fmt" if they were reading it as-is. It might be confusing to people if they wrote "fmt" and said "format" in their head.

Comment: Why not just call it "format" from the start? "fmt" only saves 3 characters.  Developers have enough acronymns to remember as it is!

Comment: I've also heard people call stdin and stdout "stud in" and "stud out" but in my head whenver I read/write them I say "standard". But I guess "stud" and "fumt" are quicker to say. Not much quicker, but still technically quicker.