# What do the fmt functions stand for?

Tags: go

The package name `fmt` [stands for "format"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23597237/707381). I am quite confused by the function names inside the package. Are the following correct?

- `Sprint` stands for "string print"?
- `Sscan` stands for "string scan"?
- `Fprint` stands for "format print"?
- `Fscan` stands for "format scan"?
- `Printf` stands for "print format"?

Comment: a simple doc of all of them: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More or less. Except that `F*` things are file related

- Fprint stands for "file print"
- Fscan stands for "file scan"

Where "file" means "an IO object".

Those names might look confusing, but actually they match names from C stdlib, which exists since the last millennium! :) As Go is positioned as system programming language, it is natural that they mimic API of the other system language.

Comment: Ok, I'll summarise! `Print*` functions print to standard output. `Fprint*` functions "print" (i.e. write) to a "file" (i.e. an `io.Writer`). `Sprint*` functions "print to a string" (i.e. return a string). Those are quite confusing names!

Comment: @Randomblue: the names come from a long history of using the standard POSIX functions: `printf`, `fprintf`, `sprintf`, not to mention a host of others in various C libs:  `snprintf, wprintf , fwprintf, swprintf, asprintf, dprintf, vprintf, vfprintf, vsprintf, vsnprintf, vasprintf, vdprintf`